# What part is expensive in the following query?

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I would be grateful if someone out there would help me figure out what's the most expensive part of the following SQL query:

```
SELECT a.*, c.id AS companyid, c.name AS companyname, 
CONCAT_WS(" ",fname,lname) AS name, c.alias as co_alias, 
count(DISTINCT(amprop.prop_id)) AS prop_count
FROM #__iproperty_agents as a
LEFT JOIN #__iproperty_agentmid as amprop ON amprop.agent_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN #__iproperty_companies as c on c.id = a.company
WHERE a.state = 1 AND c.state = 1 AND a.featured = 1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY RAND()
```

This query takes more than 20 seconds to execute which is ridiculous. The CMS is joomla 3.15 and this is a query in iproperty joomla component.

```
id select_type table  type   possible_keys key                        key_len ref                           rows   Extra
 1 SIMPLE      a      ALL    company       NO INDEX KEY COULD BE USED NULL    NULL                          8      using where; Using temporary; Using tilesort
 1 SIMPLE      c      eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY                    4       daily_dailyrealsnew.a.company 1      using where
 1 SIMPLE      amprop index  agent_id      prop_id                    8       NULL                          229294 Using index
```

Comment: How big is your DB? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: please show the execution plan of this query

Comment: Post [**`EXPLAIN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) plan of your query

Comment: Without knowing the output of EXPLAIN, consider ORDER BY RAND() as a cause, not using indexes are another possibility.

Comment: why do you need Order by RAND(), what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @wumm MySql version: 5.1.73-cll

Comment: That's a bit old, from 2006 or so I believe. Can't you upgrade?

Comment: @avisheks Well, I'm looking at this code for the first time myself. I have a task to figure out slowness of the site, and I'm trying to  debug all. Yeah ORDER BY RAND() seems useless here..

Comment: Not related to your question, but filtering on c.state = 1 in the where clause changes the outer join to an inner join.

Comment: If you are trying to print the random rows to diff time you visit the page, well there are diff ways of achieving that. Generally speaking ORDER BY RAND() kills up all your resources and CPU if data grows big.

Comment: @avisheks Thanks for your insight. I removed the ORDER BY and tested quickly , and the query was quick! I will have to figure out now why the orig dev needed the random order. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT a.*, c.id AS companyid, c.name AS companyname, 
       CONCAT_WS(" ",fname,lname) AS name, c.alias as co_alias, 
       count(DISTINCT(amprop.prop_id)) AS prop_count
FROM #__iproperty_agents as a LEFT JOIN
     #__iproperty_agentmid as amprop
     ON amprop.agent_id = a.id LEFT JOIN
     #__iproperty_companies as c
     on c.id = a.company
WHERE a.state = 1 AND c.state = 1 AND a.featured = 1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY RAND() ;
```

To really understand it, you need to look at the explain.  Some indexes would help.  Let me assume all the `id`s are primary keys and hence efficiently indexed.  Then indexes on `#__iproperty_agents(state, featured)` and `#__iproperty_companies(state)` might help.

It is quite possible that what is killing performance is the `group by`.  You can try using correlated subqueries instead.  With the right indexes, this should perform pretty well:

```
SELECT a.*, c.id AS companyid, c.name AS companyname, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, lname) AS name, c.alias as co_alias, 
       (select count(distinct amprop.prop_id)
        from #__iproperty_agentmid amprop
        where amprop.agent_id = a.id
       ) as prop_count
FROM #__iproperty_agents a LEFT JOIN
     #__iproperty_companies c
     on c.id = a.company
WHERE a.state = 1 AND c.state = 1 AND a.featured = 1
ORDER BY RAND() ;
```

For this query, you want an index on `#__iproperty_agentmid(agent_id, prop_id)`.  Using the correlated subquery removes the outer `group by`, which can improve performance.